# Does the "category" of RJ45 female connector affect possible speeds/quality?

Tags: ethernet, rj-45, cat6

Simply enough - if you connect an RJ45 connected marketed as "CAT5e", to a CAT6a cable & network, will it affect speeds or quality? is it just marketing? Or is there an actual difference between those rated CAT6 and CAT5

Comment: There is almost definitely difference in the connector, but if anything it is likely to be to accommodate the slightly increased wire diameter and to improve tolerance and spacing of wires. Per the answer you've gotten from John I doubt that it will make a *real* difference to any given cable unless you have a large number of these connections between your two machines as a tiny effect can multiply up to something big. A single cable is almost certainly fine, going through 50 different cables would probably be a problem irrespective of the connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot of difference in the actual female connection. I use both types of cable in my network here and all my network gear has standard female connectors.

http://www.cables-solutions.com/does-cat6-on-cat5e-patch-panel-or-cat5e-on-cat6-patch-panel-work.html

> There isn’t much practical difference in the patch panels themselves.
> There is a difference in the wire gauge specified between Cat5e/Cat5
> vs Cat6 Ethernet cable. The Cat6 wire is thicker. Cat6 usually has
> 23AWG copper conductors compared to only 24 AWG in Cat5e cable.
> Another factor making Cat6 a larger wire than Cat5e is the fact that
> between each of the four pairs in a Cat6 cable there is a spline that
> will separate each pair from one another.

Comment: I'd second this, from an electronics perspective you only really start worrying about the actual connector itself when you get into the RF ranges above 500MHz as before there the tiny length of mismatch at the connector is irrelevant compared to the length of the cable section the signal is going down. Even gigabit is still only [125MHz](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/ethernet-ieee-802-3/gigabit-ethernet-1ge-1000-base-t.php) which sounds high, but is not *that* high in the grand scheme. So long as you don't have lots of these mismatches you're probably fine.

Comment: Agreed. For the most part, we are not affected in the applications where we have both kinds of cable.